# Angular Naming Convention

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently learning Angular|AngularJS|Angular.js. I'm curious, is there an official name for this AWESOME framework? If so, what is it?

I see AngularJS used a lot with 'Angular' being the brevity option. However, I personally prefer Angular.js because I see projections like Angular.dart highlighting one of Angular's strong points.

In my mind, I view it as

Angular - The name of the framework (like .NET)
.[Language]

My opinions aside, I'm trying to learn if there's an 'official' name. Is it AngularJS or Angular.js?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia it's AngularJS.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS